# JQuery this in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use JQuery $(this) in a javascript object:

```
function A{
    $('.test').on('click',function(e){console.log($(this))})
}
```

But onClick console.log returns the A object and not the clicked element.
Is there a way to get the clicked element ?

I also try with e.target, but I have the html element

Thanks.

Comment: can you replace the code in your question with the code you are actually using? as it is now, that code should be throwing an error.

Comment: $(.test) should be $(".test")

Comment: *"But onClick console.log returns the A object and not the clicked element"* that is not what it should be doing. Create a fiddle reproducing your problem, as it is now your code does not recreate the issue you are describing. http://jsfiddle.net/5WLNz/

Comment: There's no way the outer function equals `this` inside the anonymous function in the event handler.

Comment: You deleted your last question :P I think I had fixed it(http://jsfiddle.net/4VGcd/2/).

Comment: @JasonSperske I solve it too, the pos was a string and not an integer :)

Comment: I was literally just typing that sentence :P  Glad you got it sorted out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function A{
    $('.test').on('click',function(e){console.log($(e.target))})
}
```

or

```
function A{
    $('.test').click(function(e){console.log($(e.target))})
}
```

will give you the jquery object.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YpJs3/1/